# HR did not call up for a second Interview. Do I have to contact the Assistant Manager?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, human-resources, follow-up

I attended an Interview on **April 21st** with a company. The Senior Manager and HR Executive interviewed me for the first round. I am afraid it did not go well as I could not meet one of their skills.

I followed up with HR  Executive on **May 2nd** to know the status. He replied

> As said earlier, your candidature has been referred to IT department
>   and they would like to meet you for next process.  I am awaiting some
>   internal clearance post which shall schedule an discussion with CIO.

But I didn't get any calls for next three weeks, so I made a call to HR Executive on **May 28th** to follow  up the process. He replied he has not got any information from higher official yet. I waited again for a week and mailed to Senior Manager on **June 9th**. But no response yet.

I am worried now whether to follow up or leave this Job as it's bugging me everyday.

1. Any idea why there is no response?
2. Do I have to call Senior Manager itself to know the status instead of mailing again?
3. Is it proper to mail the Assistant General Manager to ask about the status of an application? The reason why I would do this is because the Assistant GM helped me to forward my resume to Senior Manager in the beginning.

Comment: "I was hoping it did not go well as I could not meet one of their skills." I do not understand that sentence. It says you don't want the job, but apparently you want it very much?

Comment: Anyway, I would do nothing at this point. You have followed up several times. Anything more does only make you look desperate. The ball is in their court now.

Comment: @ Roland They told me they wanted one skill which i didn't have in the first interview. So i thought myself it  didn't go well. But when i followed up again, they wanted to call me for second Interview

Comment: So "I was hoping"  should be changed to "I suspect" or even "I'm afraid"?

Comment: Just one man's opinion Dhivya, for this one I'd just "let it go" - bad luck, better luck next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why there is no response?

The recruiting process is long by essence. There's a lot of steps, and probably a lot of candidates that passed the first step to process. Especially in a big company where you have to get approval of more people and communication between departments can be harder, slowing the process.

> Do I have to call Senior Manager itself to know the status instead of
>   mailing again?

This is a big company, constantly calling the Senior Manager won't accelerate the process, and if they really want to hire you, you'll get an update sometime anyway.

> Is it a proper way to mail Assistant General Manager to ask about
>   status?    because Assistant GM helped me to forward my resume to
>   Senior Manager in the beginning.

Nothing prevents you from doing it but then again, slow process and maybe they just evicted you. If that's the case, they won't call to tell you most of the time, because a big company won't "waste time" on people they won't hire.

The main question here shouldn't be if you can "harass" the employees of this company until you get an answer (even if that can be very frustrating). The real question is what are you going to do while they don't answer?

**I'd suggest to just assume for now that you didn't get the job and they didn't tell you**.

Do interviews, clean your suit and keep looking for a job without thinking all the time about "Why didn't they answer me?" because no one will be able to answer you why.

Comment: Its been a month.  That's way way way too much time.  This isn't just slow, this is them ignoring him on purpose.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've had hiring processes take 6 months before I got a positive response, sometimes it takes time.

Comment: @Draken then you were about their 20th choice and everyone else turned down the offer. The only reason a hiring process takes that long is if they can't find a qualified candidate. If they don't try to schedule interview 2 within a week then they aren't interested

Comment: @GabeSechan Actually the job position was closed, due to internal budget issues, and then re-opened later. Sometimes red tape gets in the way, hence why you don't assume they are ignoring on purpose.

Comment: @Draken then they tell you that, and if it makes sense later you can pick things up again. But they aren't even doing that I this case- they're ignoring him. If it was red tape, they'd be giving him status updates so he stays interested.

Comment: @GabeSechan You're assuming a competent HR team, who are very customer focused, and are in possession of all the facts. Sometimes that really isn't the case. Bureaucracy can cause lots of wonderful delays that are difficult to communicate.

Comment: @Draken Maybe we should move it to chat.

Answer (score 0):

They're ignoring you.  It's rude, but they either decided you aren't a good enough fit and they aren't interested, or they're keeping you on the hook as a fallback in case things fall through.  Otherwise there's no reason for things to take a month.

There's also the small possibility they confused you with someone else.  "As said earlier, your candidature has been referred"... but he didn't say that earlier.  Which means he may have sent that response thinking you were another candidate.  In fact this seems highly likely to me, and that you've been dropped.

At this point I'd just assume the job isn't going to work and move on.

Comment: That's some assumption, some times the hiring process can take time. I agree with the moving on sentiment, but I wouldn't assume they are ignoring the OP

Comment: @Draken if it took a week or so? Sure. Two? Maybe. A month? Either they aren't actually interested in filling the job, or they aren't interested in the OP. nobody takes that long to schedule a 2nd interview.

Comment: Yes they do, I know. Had it happen to me before...

Comment: @Draken no, they don't. They threw you out then came back to your application when they were desperate. Nobody waits more than a week, 2 at the outside for a second interview. And no interviewer would still respond after 6 months unless they were desperate. If you need to fill a position and have a qualified person, you grab him immediately. You don't wait.